# fill right side of stringstream variable with '0' c++

Tags: c++

I have the next code:

```
ofstream dataIndex;
dataIndex.open("file");

index="2222";
std::stringstream sstr1;
sstr1<<index<<'1';
sstr1<<setfill('0')<<setw(index.length()-9);
string index1= sstr1.str();
dataIndex<<index1;

dataIndex.close()
```

and i hope the result:

```
2222100000
```

but only i get

```
22221
```

without zeros? what happened?

Comment: You're setting the width to -5, for one.

Comment: call `setw` first and use a positive value.

Comment: FWIW, http://ideone.com/2koCM. That's just to illustrate the previous points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

manipulators are applied to the stream the same as input. For them to take effect they need to be applied first. For example here is how you would fill zeros on a string stream.

```
std::string index("2222");
std::ostringstream sstr1;
sstr1 << std::setw(9) << std::setfill('0') << index << '1';
std::cout << sstr1.str(); // 0000022221
```

If you want to fill differently then simply add in a direction manipulator like `std::left`, `std::right`, etc.

```
std::string index("2222");
std::ostringstream sstr1;
sstr1 << index << std::setw(10-index.length()) << std::setfill('0') << std::left << '1';
std::cout << sstr1.str(); // 2222100000
```

Comment: I'd change the output to `sstr1.str()`.

Comment: Sure, just tossed it together in 5 minutes. Obviously, you would probably want calculated width for whatever you were really doing as well and wrap it all in a simple function.

Answer (score 11):

Use [`std::left`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) to left justify the output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
  std::string s( "2222" );

  std::cout << std::setw(9) 
            << std::setfill('0') 
            << std::left 
            << s 
            << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
222200000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setw() manipulator is invoked with a negative number (the length of Index string is just 4). That might be the culprit.